# Programmatically open a list menu under one of the items in action bar

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a menu that lives in the action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:asam="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

...

   <item android:id="@+id/map_types_item"
     android:title="@string/map_menu_map_type_text"
     asam:showAsAction="always"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_bar_map"
     android:menuCategory="system"
     android:orderInCategory="300">

         <menu android:id="@+id/map_types_menu">
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/map_type_normal"
                    android:title="@string/map_type_normal_text"
                    />

                <item android:id="@+id/map_type_satellite"
                    android:title="@string/map_type_satellite_text"
                    />

                <item android:id="@+id/map_type_hybrid"
                    android:title="@string/map_type_hybrid_text"
                    />
            </group>
        </menu>


     </item>
</menu>
```

And I would like to programitcally click that button such that the menu opens in the action bar.

Is that possible?

Tried:

```
mapTypeMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.map_types_item);
```

OR

```
mapTypeMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.map_types_menu);
```

Only `R.id.map_types_item` is found.

Then to programmatically open:

```
onOptionsItemSelected(mapTypeMenuItem);
```

Is this possible?  If so what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This image shows my action bar.  The map icon it the one I am programmatically trying to click:

[image]

This image shows what it looks like when clicked from the UI.  I would like to open that programmatically as well:

[image]

Comment: How about you extract the map_types_item handling from your `onOptionsItemSelected` / `onMenuItemSelected` method into a separate method, and then call that method from the other function instead of doing this menu-finding workaround?

Comment: I don't handle that top menu, Android does.  When I click it in the UI (from action bar) it opens a menu underneath the action bar.  I do not want to programmatically click the children items, I want to just programmatically open the menu underneath the action bar.

Comment: No, I want to open the menu under one of my icons in the action bar.  Not the default menu.

Comment: I don't think that's (easily) possible, nor good UI practice, that menu is opened by the ActionBar object. I suggest you to create an additional dialog with those options, shouldn't take more than a couple lines. Then you can definitely call the menu option handler to execute the action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720804/android-open-menu-from-a-button).

---

Call `menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.map_types_item, 0);`.

Comment: No, I want to open the menu under one of my icons in the action bar. Not the default menu.  Check the xml I have an item (in the action bar) that has a menu in it.  When clicked in UI it drops down the options.  I would also like to be able to programmatically do that.